# A contact form in angular is crashing with error Error: NG0201: No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-ngmodel, angular-validation

I used an interface for the form inputs in an angular project, I have imported the interface in the contact.component.ts file and imported FormsModule in the app.module.ts there are no compilation errors but the contact page does not show when I try to view it. I would appreciate helpful responses. I also have issues with validation of the input, which I tried to do it with this code in the HTML,

```
      <div [hidden]="message.valid || message.pristine"
  class="alert alert-danger">
```

Message is required

-->

it says   src/app/components/contact/contact.component.ts:14:16
14   templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ContactComponent.

Error: src/app/components/contact/contact.component.html:104:46 - error TS2339: Property 'pristine' does not exist on type 'HTMLTextAreaElement'.

104      <div [hidden]="message.valid || message.pristine"
~~~~~~~~

src/app/components/contact/contact.component.ts:14:16
14   templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ContactComponent.

Here is my contact.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormControl,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Contact } from 'src/app/contact';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })





@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  reasons=  [ 'Company hire' ,
   'Client quote request', 
 'Others'];
 model = new Contact('Zainab Afolabi', 
'zainab.o.afolabi@gmail.com','I want a fee quote request for a 
fintech support dashboard', 'excellent', 'subscribe');

 submitted = false;

 onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }

 newContact() {
   this.model = new Contact('', '','','','');
 }


  contactForm:FormGroup=new FormGroup ({
    email:new FormControl ("", Validators.email),
    phoneNumber:new FormControl ("", Validators.required),
    message:new FormControl ("", Validators.required),

  });
  contactFormLoading: boolean = false;
  email:string='';
  phoneNumber:string='';
  message:string='';

  constructor() {   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  contact() {
this.contactFormLoading = true;
let data = {
  
  email: this.contactForm.value.email,
  phoneNumber: this.contactForm.value.phoneNumber,
  message:this.contactForm.value.message

    };
}
// onSubmit(contactForm:FormGroup){

//   console.log(this.contactForm.value);
```

// }
}

Comment: Kindly share your component code.

Comment: Do you have somthing in your component template have something like  `<textarea #message>` tag

Comment: In your component there'e nothing "message" (a variable or a getter or a template reference variable). If you want get the formControl, you can use a getter: `get message(){return this.contactForm.get('message')}`. After this, you can always use the "safe operator" -the "?" before the "."- to avoid initials errors:`[hidden]="message?.valid || message?.pristine"`

Comment: Thank you so much @Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen, 
, I have resolved the issue. I simply commented out the first form I created in the html file. It had a div with an input type of text-area.